# Is spark partition size is equal to HDFS block size or depends on the number of cores available on all executors?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking through spark partitioning and I see different answers for the question.
Is spark partition size is equal to HDFS block size or depends on the number of cores available on all executors?, and Does the performance improves by repartitioning the data in skewed data case? (I assume the data related to the same join key is again shuffled back to a single executor during the join). Please help me understand this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your data where from you are reading. If you are reading from **HDFS**, then one block will be one partition. But if you are reading a **parquet file**, then one parquet file is one partition as it is not splittable, so depending on the block in case of HDFS and files count in case of parquet, it creates partitions.

Regarding the skewed data, the more data one partition has, the more time it takes to finish the execution. The other tasks will finished quickly as they have less data so the resources are not being utilized properly. Therefore, it is always better to repartition the skewed data properly, so all executors can evenly do the execution.

You can look here for all the available RDDs, and how they are creating partitions:
https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd

Comment: Thanks for the answer, **I think parquet files are actually splittable by RowGroups with/without compression** and regarding skewed data If I have a dataset evenly distributed by a partitioner but as it is skewed during the join time the data with same join key is again shuffled to the same executor, how does that help in performance??

Comment: If you see here, scroll to the bottom, they mentioned that gzip and snappy are not splittable and generally these 2 are used to compress parquet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bigdatasupport/why-is-my-spark-application-running-out-of-disk-space please correct me if im wrong regarding the splits.

Comment: Regarding the skew data while joining, you need to analyze your data first and if your data is being skewed because of join, then you need to introduce another key to split that chunk into multiple, so it can be executed evenly.

Comment: That's confusing now. According to this, parquet with snappy are splittable. https://boristyukin.com/is-snappy-compressed-parquet-file-splittable/

Comment: Thanks, Waqar for your response...After going through a series of articles, it seems it's good to have partitions 2-3x times of the number of cores to achieve max concurrency and also considering in mind that max shuffle size should be less than 2GB. In regards to data skew, it seems other techniques like salting or iterative broadcasting helps(on larger datasets).